# How to align the console output to decimal point instead of left or right

Tags: c++, console-application, cout

I am trying to align the console output in C++ to a decimal point. I have tried the `setw`, `precision` options and other flags that aligns to `right` or `left`.

But none of those has worked satisfactorily.

The closest option is to use `showpos` to print (+) sign for positive numbers, but it disturbs the other formatting such as "TE_1_0" to "TE_+1_+0"

```
1.000000    -0.000000   0.000000
-0.000000   1.000000    0.000000
0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
```

It will be nice to have it aligned to decimal point to present the output to the people who are interested in. So any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe show your code? [mcve]

Comment: How about different formatting for negative and non-negative values? To make sure that non-negative values gets an extra space to account for the `-` printed for negative numbers.

Comment: Its a matrix so I don't really print element by elemnts in rows and columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `setw`, `setfill`, `fixed` and `setprecesion` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec{{10.0233, 122.1, 1203.1},{100.03, 22.15, 3.01},{107.03, 152.1, 0.1},};
    for(std::vector<double> tempVec: vec)
    {
        for(double elem: tempVec)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(8) << std::setfill(' ') << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << elem << "    ";
        }
        std::cout<< std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
  10.023     122.100    1203.100    
 100.030      22.150       3.010    
 107.030     152.100       0.100
```

If you modify the above example slightly as shown below:

```
std::cout << std::setw(12) << std::setfill(' ') << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << elem << "    ";
```

Then the output becomes:

```
   10.023300      122.100000     1203.100000    
  100.030000       22.150000        3.010000    
  107.030000      152.100000        0.100000
```

`setw` is used to set the maximum length of the output, which was 8 and 12 in my given example.

`setfill` is used to fill the padding places with a `char`.